# running total sum/count

Tags: sql, oracle

I am wondering how I would add totals. I need to add all the sale_id by person. It should look like below. I can pull in the sale_name and sale_id but i'm unsure how to create a column and row that totals like sale_num below. Thanks.

```
sale_Name sale_id sale_num

Jim Thomas 157452
Jim Thomas 153352
Jim Thomas 198762
Jim Thomas 3
Bill Simpson 254854 
Bill Simpson 265782
Bill Simpson 233122 
Bill Simpson 257411 
Bill Simpson 4
```

Comment: Add proper sample data and expected output

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: Normally, you don't output different data in the same column (in your example `sale_id` resultset column contains sale_id in some rows and result of aggregation in others)... However, you may get desired output with `UNION [ALL]`. I'd prefer to use analytical clause and have running total as a separate column.   Also, what is the point of having `sale_num` column which is always empty?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE sale_Name = 'Jim';
```

Comment: What does this do for salespeople named something other than `Jim`?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you `sale_num` as a separate column as opposed to a separate row as you have it in your expected output:

```
SELECT sale_name, sale_id, COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY sale_name ) AS sale_num
  FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see subtotals in your result, you can try `rollup` function, for example:

```
with t as
(
select 'Jim Thomas' sale_name, 157452 sale_id from dual union all
select 'Jim Thomas' sale_name, 153352 sale_id from dual union all
select 'Jim Thomas' sale_name, 198762 sale_id from dual union all

select 'Bill Simpson' sale_name, 254854 sale_id from dual union all
select 'Bill Simpson' sale_name, 265782 sale_id from dual union all
select 'Bill Simpson' sale_name, 233122 sale_id from dual union all
select 'Bill Simpson' sale_name, 257411 sale_id from dual 
)
SELECT sale_name, sale_id, count(sale_id) FROM t
GROUP BY rollup(sale_name, sale_id)
ORDER BY 1,2
```